# Apply multiple tags to an object during uploading via aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

What's the correct syntax to upload an object with multiple tags?
Following command with 1 tag works fine:

```
aws s3api put-object --bucket mybucket --key something/obj.txt --body obj.txt --tagging "mykeyname1=myvalue1"
```

But following command with multiple tags generates error:

```
aws s3api put-object --bucket mybucket --key something/obj.txt --body obj.txt --tagging "mykeyname1=myvalue1, mykeyname2=myvalue2"
```

Error

```
An error occurred (InvalidArgument) when calling the PutObject operation: The header 'x-amz-tagging' shall be encoded as UTF-8 then URLEncoded URL query parameters without tag name duplicates
```

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately the [documentation](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3api/put-object.html) is not the best in this case. You can have multiple tags using the following format: `key1=value1&key2=value2`

For example:

```
aws s3api put-object --bucket mybucket --key something/obj.txt --body obj.txt --tagging 'mykeyname1=myvalue1&mykeyname2=myvalue2'
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the answer.